# Sitecore 8 Update 5 FieldChanges functionality during publish

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc

We are using Sitecore 8 update-5. We would like to check which values changed in a specific field during a publish. For this we are subscribed to the item:saved event handler. When extracting the ItemChanges parameter from the event arguments we use the FieldChanges property for that field. In the master database the FieldChanges dictionary contains only those fields that were changed and FieldChanges.OriginalValue and FieldChanges.Value contains the proper values (the old ones and the new ones). However when publishing from master to web DB it seems that the FieldChanges always contain all fields and the OriginalValue and Value properties are always the same. We tested this with items which were already existing in web database, using smart publish and a single language.

The question is this is how it should work or is this a bug?

Some example code:

```
var topicFieldID = new ID(RelatedTopic.FieldIDs.Topics); //getting the field ID

var changes = Event.ExtractParameter<ItemChanges>(args, 1); //in item:saved event handler

var oldIDs = changes.FieldChanges[topicFieldID]?.OriginalValue?.ToString().Split('|');
var newIDs = changes.FieldChanges[topicFieldID]?.Value?.ToString().Split('|');
```

and in our case the "oldIDs" and "newIDs" contain the same values in web DB

Regards,
Chris